# AppBar longer than screen width

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, androiddesignsupport, android-appbarlayout

I am trying to create a user profile layout which has a standard Coordinator layout nesting an app bar with a Collapsing toolbar. Collapsing toolbar contains a header with background hero image, with profile image and his details. After that there is a linear layout with his user followers information, then user interests, then recent places and then a horizontal scroll with his album and then a tab layout (Making my AppBar a long one)

Outside the appbar I have a View pager.

When scrolling I want the toolbar to pin and tabs to stick.

> 

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/userprofileAppbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/profile_background_color"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_layout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/gradient_bottom"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="25dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="22dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
            app:statusBarScrim="@color/gradient_bottom">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/user_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:background="@color/user_background_color"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <com.example.local.ui.RoundedImage
                    android:id="@+id/user_profile_pic"
                    android:layout_width="78.7dp"
                    android:layout_height="78.7dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_avatar" />

                <com.example.local.buddycloud.customviews.TypefacedTextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13.7dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Monika Singh"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <com.example.local.buddycloud.customviews.TypefacedTextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Lives in Sushant Lok 1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <com.example.local.buddycloud.customviews.TypefacedTextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_follow_button"
                    style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20.7dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_follow_button"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="+ FOLLOW"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    app:fontType="@string/font_regular" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="none"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/followers_following_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="14.7dp"
                android:paddingTop="14dp">

                /// Followers and Following for the user

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/below_followers_following_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1px"
                android:background="@color/divider" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/about_user_card_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="13.3dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="0dp">

                // About user content
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/user_interests_card_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8.3dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:visibility="gone"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="17.3dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    // Interests of the user

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/user_recent_places_card_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8.3dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:visibility="gone"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                // Recent places visted by user

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/user_photos_card_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8.3dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                // Horizontal scroll of user photos
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/user_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/light_blue_color"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3.3dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/user_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This works fine on large screen phones but on small screen the height of appbar layout is coming out larger than the screen height so it is getting truncated.

I could have put the extra header into a Recycler view if it was a single list but i am using a ViewPager.

I tried putting this extra header content after appbar into a Nested scroll with viewpager but then my viewpager did not come up. Being desperate I even tried playing around with two Appbars but that did not pan out either.

Any solution that builds on not customizing behavior of layout in code is preferred. Thanks in advance

Comment: I will update with a screenshot asap, but why do you think scroll_flags are an issue? Does AppBar allow scrolling on its own content?

Comment: Hard to say but, let's see the screenshots and then i will check it out.That is strange because you said it's working on `large screen`.